# using a for-loop on elements within multiple lists

Tags: python, for-loop

I have multiple lists. I want to run a for-loop on the items of each list

### Attempt 1

```
foo = ["today", "tomorrow", "yesterday"] 
bar = ["What", "is", "chocolate"]
empty = []
for x in [foo, bar]:
    empty.append("mushroom" + x)
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

### Attempt 2

```
foo = ["today", "tomorrow", "yesterday"] 
bar = ["What", "is", "chocolate"] 
def shroom(x):
  print("mushroom" + x)
map(shroom, bar, foo)
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: shroom() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

My desired output would be two new variables, where each element in each list to have "mushroom" appended on.

```
fooMushroom = [mushroomtoday, mushroomtomorrow, mushroomyesterday]
fooBar = [mushroomWhat,mushroomis,mushroomchocolate]
```

### Note: I do not want pairs using Zip

i.e., I do not want each element from each list to be paired, via zip or a similar function. I need the output of foo and bar to be saved in a variable seperately, not merged/paired.

Comment: does all the lists have equal number of elements?

Comment: Could you provide the expected output?

Comment: expected output added

Comment: To those that have marked it as a duplicate, can you please explain how? I have a feeling you haven't understood the original question, or i'm failing to see how it applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate your list:

`for x in foo + bar:
    empty.append("mushroom" + x)`

I didn't see your wanted output. You could use dictionaries for clarity.

```
orig_data = {
"foo": ["a", "b", "c"],
"bar": ["a", "b", "c"]
}
mushroom_data = {}

for k,v in orig_data.iteritems():
    for x in v:
        if k not in mushroom_data:
            mushroom_data[k] = []
        mushroom_data[k].append("mushroom" + x)

print mushroom_data
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks Shiriu, despite my initial code, i'm trying to save the output of foo and bar into two new variables (please see desired output in above post). Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You could iterate on a list of list etc. But I am not sure where is your issue there. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: When I run the new code, it returns this error code. `Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 2)`

Comment: @G.Gip Sorry, I did it quickly yesterday without testing. Here it should be working fine (tested this time)

Answer (score -1):

I know you said you didn't want to use zip, but in this way you get each element in its own variable, which is what you want no?

```
fooMushroom = []
barMushroom = []
for x, y in zip(foo, bar):
    fooMushroom.append("mushroom"+x)
    barMushroom.append("mushroom"+y)
```

Comment: or list comprenhension: `["mushroom" + ' '.join(i) for i in zip(foo,bar)]`

Comment: Not quite. Please check desired output.

Comment: check my edit, simply changed the output but the basis remains the same

Comment: Unfortunately it becomes cumbersome to add a `append` for each list/variable, especially when you have multiple lists. 

The reason I want a for-loop/function solution is to prevent the need to add a `append` line for each list.

Is there a way to automate it so the for-loop spits out fooMushroom, BarMushroom, without having to manually type append for each list in the loop?